# Emitter Follower, \$V_{out}\$ smaller than \$V_{in}\$

Tags: circuit-design, emitter-follower

If we were to connect a sufficiently large resistor to a signal generator, we would expect to measure the voltage over the large resistor to be the voltage amplitude of the signal. However, if we add a transistor and make an emitter follower, using that same large resistor (or even larger), the total voltage drop over the resistor is now smaller than the voltage amplitude of the signal. Why is this the case?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about large signals (swings comparable to Vcc) or small signals (small deviation relative to a positive bias)?

Comment: signal amplitudes of about 100mV from the singal amplifyer, V_CC ~10-15V

Comment: What's the mean Vb (bias)? Also, what's the time scale (frequency, pulse width, rise time, whatever is most important)?

Comment: I just checked v_b=1.699975 Frequency is 1kHz or slightly larger

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @David - Hi, It seems you asked your question on both EE.SE and Physics.SE, who have now migrated your question from there to here, so now we have both of them. Obviously I have closed this migrated one as a duplicate of the one you already asked here. However you seem to have given *slightly* different details in the two questions (e.g. you mention Vcc in this one, but not in the question asked originally on EE.SE) so I won't merge them (at least, not yet). || Please *do not* ask the same question on multiple SE sites - it is [*strongly discouraged*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

OK, based on the clarifications in the comments, (low frequency, small signal, modest bias) I'll tackle this with the linearized [Ebers-Moll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Ebers%E2%80%93Moll_model) model. The effective small-signal emitter resistance \$dV_e/dI_e\$ is \$\approx V_t/I_e\$, where \$V_t\$ is the "thermal voltage" about 26mV at room temperature.

For 1.7V bias, the emitter voltage will be about 1V. For a 1kΩ load, that's an emitter current of 1mA, so the emitter resistance is 26Ω. That forms a voltage divider with the 1k load, so you get a voltage gain of about 0.975. Note that the emitter resistance is inversely proportional to emitter current, so increasing the resistor doesn't help much.

To get gain closer to 1, you need to increase the load resistance without reducing the emitter current. You can do that by using a higher bias or by driving the emitter resistor with a negative supply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, wondering if you could clarify this. I have found for high resistors ~5000ohm, my voltage drop over R_E is 0.08mV rather that going to 0.1mV. Why would this be the case?

Comment: @David I'm unclear on what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I connected my signal generator (sin wave amplitude 100mV) up to an oscilloscope, then I also connected the output of my circuit to my oscilloscope. The output signal pk-pk (top of peak to bottom of trough)value only approached 80mv. Is there a reason for this to change?

Comment: Are you sure you're using 5000Ω? For much higher resistance, the circuit will slow down, and you'll see smaller signals. What does the output look like for a square wave from your generator?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not with my equipment at this moment, I tried from 0.1 Ohm to 10000 Ohm resistor trying to see how voltage drop changed vs resistance. I found that a sharp increase in voltage drop from 0.1 to 1000 Ohm then it plateaus 80mV

Comment: @David Do you perhaps mean kΩ? For load resistance <20Ω I would expect to see smoke from the transistor.